# Restrict parameter to specific type; when using CimInstance

Tags: powershell, parameters, wmi, powershell-v5.1, cim

Is there a sensible way to restrict the parameter type used for a function when it may be encapsulated in a `CimInstance`?

e.g. Say I have a method such as below:

```
function Add-DaclAce {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Void])] #just for the MVP
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateScript({$_.CimClass.CimClassName -eq 'Win32_SecurityDescriptor'})]
        [System.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance]$SecurityDescriptor
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateScript({$_.CimClass.CimClassName -eq 'Win32_ACE'})]
        [System.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance]$NewDaclAce
    )
    $SecurityDescriptor.DACL.Add($NewDaclAce) | Out-Null
}
```

Question?

- Is there a better way to enforce the type of the parameters; i.e. using the parameter type, instead of a validation script?
- Is there a way to make the implementation agnostic of CIM vs WMI, so that it only cares that the object is a SecurityDescriptor/Access Control Entry?

i.e. My requirement is only that the first parameter be a [security descriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/secrcw32prov/win32-securitydescriptor), and my second an [ACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/secrcw32prov/win32-ace); but because I'm using CIM to fetch these in my current implementation, they happen to be of type `CimInstance`.  I then wish to enforce that they represent the correct underlying objects, so have to use `ValidateScript` to check the `CimClass`.  However, the use of CIM is an arbitrary detail from the perspective of this function; it

Comment: I asked this exact question a while back, let me find it for you.

Comment: Nice one, thanks; sorry, didn't find that when searching.  Closing mine as a duplicate

Comment: As for your question about implementation agnostic, I'm not sure if that's solved for.  Maybe parameter sets that can accept one or the other?  The `#..` path remains the same, but the type is different.

Comment: Thanks.  The answer to your question was enough for my requirement / part 2 of my question was more an ideal than a need.  Sadly the `System.Object` approach didn't work, and it seems that the only common ancestor with WMI's ManagementClass; good shout though.